# CSS doesn't load the first time I connect to the website

Tags: css, wordpress, browser-cache

When I connect to a specific page of the website, the css doesn't load.
All people doesn't have the problem and it depends of the navigator they use.
The problem is just for this page.

http://tinyurl.com/nyx26zx

It works if you reload the page and it will always works after that.
Maybe it's a problem of the navigator cache ?

The website uses Wordpress and the plugin WP SUPER CACHE but I excluded the page so 
I think it's not a problem with the plugin.

Comment: No problem, I see your website with all styles when I've loaded that first time. In which browsers?

Comment: does it happen with all browser? What is the server status of the css file at the first page load?

Comment: I confirm, that the page loads just fine, clear your browser's cache and try again, tested with Opera 12 and Firefox 29.

Comment: The problem is for all browsers I think. I don't have the problem anymore but some people have it. Obviously, the css is well loaded in the code but not executed. If the person reload the page it's ok, the problem appears only the first time. It's not a big problem but I still have to fix it for the new visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off any caching you may be using; Cloudflare is a known problem in this type of situation. If you have Cloudflare enabled, turn it off.
Disable or remove WordPress Super Cache temporarily to see if this fixes the issue.

Try connecting through a VPN or proxy to see whether the problem is localized to your region, because nobody else on here is having this problem with the CSS.
Try using mine (be aware that the internet sometimes can disconnect [VPN is public]):
Server: server1.vpnfusion.com
Username/Password: vpnfusion/Password01
if the VPN doesn't work, try using another one.

Try clearing your browser's cache after doing all this.

Comment: Ok I'm going to test it and wait for visitors feed back. Thx !

Comment: I don't have feed back so I think it's ok !

Comment: @geopl I'd appreciate it if you could mark my answer as accepted, four years after you confirmed that it solved your problem.